# Type in two uitextfield at the same time

Tags: iphone, ios, uitextfield

I want to type in two uitextfield at the same time.Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using the following code:

Typein2.h - class where three textFields are declared. The "textFieldBeingEdited" textField is to know which textField (text1 or text2) is being edited

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface Typein2 : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate> {

    UITextField *text1;
    UITextField *text2;

    UITextField *textFieldBeingEdited;

}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextField *text1;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextField *text2;

@end
```

In the viewDidLoad method do the following:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    text1.delegate = self;
    text2.delegate = self;

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
     addObserver:self
     selector:@selector(changeBothFieldsText:)
     name:UITextFieldTextDidChangeNotification
     object:nil ] ;
}
```

TextField delegate Method:

```
-(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {

    if ( [textField isEqual:text1] ) {
        textFieldBeingEdited = text1;
    }
    else
        textFieldBeingEdited = text2;

}
```

changeBothFieldsText Method:

```
-(void)changeBothFieldsText:(NSNotification*)notification {

    if ( [textFieldBeingEdited isEqual:text1] ) {
        text2.text = text1.text;
    }
    else
        text1.text = text2.text;    
}
```

Comment: Just to be sure, replace pointer comparisons `(textField == text1)` with `[textField isEqual:text1]`

Answer (score 1):

I see no reason why you can't trap the changes to the text in the first UITextView and then change the text in the second.  The notification UITextViewTextDidChangeNotification and the text property should give you what you need.

Comment: I am using uitextfield not uitextview but thanks for the answer.